# Where's the best place to download Ubuntu virtual machines?

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox, and found a list of Ubuntu images [here](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/). But as of today it doesn't include an image for `14.04`, which I [need](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404) to install `GitLab` on, (or build from source).

What URLs would you suggest to ease the search for a client image of `Ubuntu 14.04`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Should this question be moved to the AskUbuntu website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image file downloads for the latest version(s) of Ubuntu (including 14.04) are listed on Ubuntu's Release/Downloads page (searchable in Google).

Here's a guide on how to install the system from the ISO format, using VirtualBox (your tool of choice):

http://www.engadget.com/2009/09/07/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-linux-on-a-mac-its-easy-and-free/

For the VirtualBox image (instead of ISO), go here (lists versions from 14-15):

http://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/

As such, it goes without saying that you should use the original source whenever possible.

Good day to you!